# Modified Stochastic Integral

Tags: proof-verification, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Suppose one has a stochastic differential equation: $$dX_t = f(X_t) dt + g(X_t)d\eta(t)$$ where $\eta$ solves the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process:

$$d\eta(t) = \lambda \eta(t) dt + \sigma dW(t)$$

Suppose $g \in L^2(\Omega \times [0,T])$. 
How, if it all, can one calculate $E\left[\int_0^T g(s) d\eta(s) \right]$?

My initial thought and there may be an error:

$E\left[\int_0^T g(s) d\eta(s) \right] = E\left[\int_0^T \lambda \eta(s) g(s) ds  + \int_{0}^{T} \sigma g(s) dW_s\right] = E\left[\int_0^T \lambda \eta(s) g(s) ds \right] = \int_0^T E\left[\lambda \eta(s) g(s) \right]ds = \int_0^T \lambda  g(s)E\left[ \eta(s) \right]ds = 0$

Comment: if you fix the issue with $E[\eta(s)]$ as pointed out by @TyrCurtis and explain why the expectation and the integral can be interchanged, then the answer will be fine.

Comment: @TyrCurtis It is true however if we assume $\eta(0) = 0$ is it not? I see that assumption made for Brownian Motion

Comment: @Calculon I believe I can switch the integral and expectation due to Fubini's Theorem since I'm assuming $g \in L^2$ (I'm trying to use an extension of this: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/84952/time-integral-of-an-ornstein-uhlenbeck-process)

Comment: @Brenton if you assume it starts from 0, it's correct